# How to show "Shipping Class" column in WooCommerce admin product list

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, backend, product

I am using woocommerce.

I know that you can show: Image, SKU, Stock, Price, Categories, Tags, Featured, and Date on the "All Products" page. I have had a look around I cannot find a way to add a "Shipping Class" column to the page.

```
 * @snippet       New Products Table Column @ WooCommerce Admin
 * @how-to        Get CustomizeWoo.com FREE
 * @author        Rodolfo Melogli
 * @compatible    WooCommerce 5
 * @donate $9     https://businessbloomer.com/bloomer-armada/
 */
 
add_filter( 'manage_edit-product_columns', 'bbloomer_admin_products_visibility_column', 9999 );
 
function bbloomer_admin_products_visibility_column( $columns ){
   $columns['visibility'] = 'Visibility';
   return $columns;
}
 
add_action( 'manage_product_posts_custom_column', 'bbloomer_admin_products_visibility_column_content', 10, 2 );
 
function bbloomer_admin_products_visibility_column_content( $column, $product_id ){
    if ( $column == 'visibility' ) {
        $product = wc_get_product( $product_id );
      echo $product->get_catalog_visibility();
    }
}
```

The code above shows if an item is visible or not. Can anyone point me in the right direct to show the product's shipping class?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To show the shipping class in Admin product list, use the following revisited code:

```
add_filter( 'manage_edit-product_columns', 'add_admin_products_shipping_class_column', 999 );
function add_admin_products_shipping_class_column( $columns ){
   $columns['shipping_class'] = __('Shipping Class', 'woocommerce');
   return $columns;
}
 
add_action( 'manage_product_posts_custom_column', 'get_admin_products_shipping_class_column_content', 10, 2 );
function get_admin_products_shipping_class_column_content( $column, $product_id ){
    if ( $column === 'shipping_class' ) {
        global $post, $product;

        if( is_a( $product, 'WC_Product' ) ) {
            $shipping_class_id = (int) $product->get_shipping_class_id();
            $shipping_class    = get_term($shipping_class_id, 'product_shipping_class');
            
            echo ! is_wp_error($shipping_class) ? $shipping_class->name : '<em>n/a</em>';
        }
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: Works fine, one thing to add, styling for the column: 

.column-shipping_class {
    position: relative;
    width: 20%;
}

Extra: you can now show/hide the column in the "screen options" on top of the admin page